# How to play music using AngularJS from selected file

Tags: angularjs, html

This is my
 code

```
<form name="downloadForm" role="form" ng-submit="download()">
    <label>
        files :
    </label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="radio left-buffer-medium" ng-repeat="file in product.issueDTO.source track by file.id">
            <input type="radio" name="fileRadio" ng-model="$parent.selectedFile.id" ng-value="{{file.id}}"
                                    ng-checked="($parent.selectedFile.id == file.id)">{{file.sourceType.extension}}
            <small>{{file.fileDescription}}</small>
        </label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" ></span>
        <span translate="qstoreappApp.product.publicproducts.download"></span>
    </button>
    <br>
    <audio controls>            
        <source src="????" type="audio/mpeg">
                        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>                                                        
</form>
```

I use it to select a file to download, and everything is works. I would like to use mp3 player from HTML5, my question is. How i can send a patch to src ?
I've tried with file.filePath, but it does'nt works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-src

`<source ng-src="http://localhost:3000/tracks/{{ ngmodelSong}}" type="audio/mpeg">`